# Using a (to a class) unknown function

Tags: c#

I have a check if a form is already open. If it't not, it will open, if it is, it will activate the form + use a SwitchTab(int i) function. Here is some code:

```
public partial class Insert : Form {
    public Insert() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Insert(int tab) : this() {
        SwitchTab(tab);
    }

    public void SwitchTab(int tab) {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tab;
    }
}

private void OpenInsert(int tab) {

        // Loop through all forms
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) {

            // Check if form of Insert type is found
            if (f.GetType() == typeof(Insert)) {
                f.Activate();

                // Unknown function
                f.SwitchTab(tab)

                return;
            }
        }

        // Not found, open form
        Insert insert = new Insert(tab);
        insert.Show();
    }
```

The reason behind this is that the Insert form has multiple tabs and I want to switch tab if an other button in the menu is clicked. The problem is that where I want to call the SwitchTab() function, the compiler doesnt know that it's a Insert class, but it only passes when it is. So is there some way to forcefully let it know it's a instance of insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to tell that it is, like so:

```
((Insert)f).SwitchTab(tab)
```

This will try to cast the form to it, but will throw an Exception if its not. But since you check it, there shouldn't be a problem :-)

Comment: Weirdly enough this worked, I tried to cast with (Insert)f.SwitchTab(), but that didn't work. With the extra parentheses it works flawless!

Comment: yes, it's because the order of how it is exectued is first the method and then the cast. The call of the method has a higher priorty than the cast

Answer (score 2):

Cast using `as` returns `null` if the object cannot be cast to the class. Also, the compiler checks if a cast is possible at all:

```
    foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) {

        var fI = f as Insert;
        // Check if form of Insert type is found
        if (fI != null) {
            fI.Activate();
            fI.SwitchTab(tab);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With linq you could do this:

```
private void OpenInsert(int tab)
{
    var insert = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Insert>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (insert == null)
    {
        insert = new Insert(tab);
        insert.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        insert.Activate();
        insert.SwitchTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Insert>().FirstOfDefault();
if(form != null) {
  form.Activate();
  form.SwitchTab(tab);
} else {
  form = new Insert(tab);
  insert.Show();
}//if
```

Comment: I saw this before and it might work, but it just seems a bit messy to me. Thanks anyway.